# Can you specify point size when using rasterize in holoviews

Tags: python, holoviews

Is it possible to specify a size for the points generated by the `rasterize` function in holoviews? Similar to that of `spread` when using `datashade`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes and no. There is a PR for that at https://github.com/pyviz/datashader/pull/771 , but it hasn't been merged into the main codebase or released yet, so it would only be available to people willing to live on the very bleeding edge.